Running C# program with local .mdf file on non-developer client
I built a C# project and created my own database, placing it in a database folder in the solution directory. This is a college project and is expected to be zipped and sent to my  professor so that he can run it and expect everything to work on his machine.
The problem lays with the directory path to the .mdf file. I used Scaffold-db to set up everything, and currently the path is directed to my users folder (where my project exists).
I have tried:
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\Database\DATABASE.mdf");

and:
// Get the Downloads folder for the current user
string downloadsPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Downloads");

// Construct the full path to the database
string databasePath = Path.Combine(downloadsPath, "DATABASE.mdf");

// Connection string using the dynamic path
string connectionString = $@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={databasePath};Integrated Security=True";

For some reason or other, neither of those options worked. I've added more directory jumps in the first option to no avail.

The following may be of interest: SQL Server Express LocalDB: Microsoft SQL Server Express LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express targeted to developers. Your instructor will have to have this installed prior running your application.

It's not clear what you're zipping and sending to your professor. Are you sending the contents of your entire solution or just what's needed to run your application (ie: .dll/.exe file)?

I'm zipping the entire solution directory. Includes the folders: bin, obj, and the self created database (with the .mdf and .ldf files) and models (with the context.cs and object for the table). The solution and all the files are going in the zip.

You can actually omit the bin and obj folders, as they will automatically be re-created when your professor builds the project.

Let's have a look at the folder structure of the solution. It will be something like this (assuming a new style-SDK project):
[Solution] Folder
    Solution.sln
    [Database] Folder
        Database.mdf
    [Project] Folder
        Project.csproj
        [bin] Folder
            [Release] or [Debug] Folder
                [net8.0] folder
                    Application.exe

If you have an old style project file (e.g. for .NET Framework 4.8), the application is directly in the Debug or Release folder.
The base directory is where the executable (*.exe) is. From there (the  [net8.0] or whatever target framework folder), you have to walk up the path with .. until you are in the solution folder. I.e., 4 times:
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    @"..\..\..\..\Database\Database.mdf");


In a comment you stated that "The .mdf is located within the project in a folder called Databases and I already have the property set to Copy if newer".
This is very different from having a Database folder in the solution (solution folder <> project folder). If you have this Database or Databases folder (not sure about the naming) in the project and you have set the .mdb to Copy if newer, then this folder along with the .mdb will be copied to the output directory and you don't have to back up with ..\. Simply write:
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    @"Database\Database.mdf"); // or @"Databases\Database.mdf"


Alternatively, you could also add the .mdf file to the project and change the project property Advanced > Copy to Ouput Directory to Copy If newer. This will copy the .mdf file to the same folder as the application .exe file or, if you add it to a subfolder of the project, to the same subfolder in the application folder.
In real world projects, you only want to distribute the files in the application folder and its subfolders to the users.

It's a Windows Forms App with .NET 8.0. The .mdf is located within the project in a folder called Databases and I already have the property set to Copy if newer

The project folder is not the same as the solution folder as you stated in the question. If you already have Copy if newer, then you don't need any .. because the Databasefolder will be directly in the base directory. Solution:string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,     @"Database\Database.mdf");`
